# Optimal Strategy for a 2 player game

Tags: algorithmic-game-theory

- 2 players A & B are playing a game involving a number *n*
- Player A makes the first move & both players play alternately.
- In each move the player takes the number n,chooses a number *i* such that *2^i < n* and replaces *n* with *k = n - 2^i* iff the number of 1s in the binary representation of *k* is greater than or equal to the number of 1s in the binary representation of *n*
- Game ends when no player can make a move, ie there does not exist such an *i*

For example:

```
n = 13 = b1101
```

Only possible i=1

```
k = n - 2^i = 11 = b1011
```

Again,only possible i = 2

```
k = n - 2^i = 7 = b111
```

Since Player A cant make any more moves, Player B wins

I've deduced that at any step,we can only choose an i,such that there is a 0 at the corresponding position in the binary representation of n.
For Example:
if n=1010010,then i can only be {0,2,3,5}.
But I cant move any further.A minimax algorithm isnt exactly striking me.I would appreciate any help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It’s a disguised version of Nim. Each block of consecutive $0$’s in the binary representation of $n$ is a pile. For example, from $10000_2$ you can subtract $8$ to get $1000_2$; $4$ to get $1100_2$; $2$ to get $111_2$; or $1$ to get $1111_2$. These moves correspond to reducing a pile of $4$ stones to $3$, $2$, $1$, or $0$ stones, respectively. I’ll leave it to you to fill in the details. You probably already know the strategy for Nim.

(This is a cute variant; I’d not seen it before.)

Comment: This doesn't seem right, since the removal of zeroes from one block will create new zeroes in the next block to the left. The value of $1010_2$, for instance, is $*$, not $0$, even there are two equal "piles" of zeroes in that number.

Comment: @Théophile: You’re right: I was concentrating so much on the case of adjacent $1$’s that I forgot that the piles get amalgamated in the basic case!

Comment: I’ll revise this when I get back.

Comment: It seems that every position has value $0$, $*$, or $*2$.